# ByteBuffer "loses" backing array when sent via WebSockets

Tags: java, websocket

**What I have:** The client sends a double-array via ByteBuffer over WebSockets to the Server. I know that at this point that the ByteBuffer has a backing array. When the Buffer arrives at the server `bytBuffer.hasArray()` evaluates to `false`

**Client-Code:**

```
private void sendData(double[] data) {

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 8);
    System.out.println("hasarray " + byteBuffer.hasArray()); // true

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        byteBuffer.putDouble(data[i]);
    }

    session.getAsyncRemote().sendBinary(byteBuffer);
}
```

**Server-Code:**

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(final ByteBuffer byteBuffer, Session session) {

    byte[] save = new byte[50 * 8];
    System.out.println("server has array " + byteBuffer.hasArray()); // false

    dataService.save(save); // EJB to persist byte[]

    for (Session client : clients) {
        try {
            if(!client.equals(session)){
                client.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(byteBuffer);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(TemperatureDispatcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Context:**
I have basically three separate applications which communicate with each other via WebSockets. The sensor(client) produces data and sends it to the server. The servers job is to send the data to another client(JavaFX Chart which displays the data) and to persist the data which has been sent to a database.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to enforce the use of a backing-array when bytes are sent via WebSockets using a ByteBuffer ?
2. Is there a better solution to persisting the `byte[]` rather than copying it to a separate `byte[]` ?

Comment: Since you're dealing with `ByteBuffers`, why do you care about the backing array?

Comment: Because I would like to persist the byte[] in the database.

Comment: Well, since you're apparently getting a native buffer, use `get(byte[] arr)` and persist that.

Comment: It works, thanks. Although I thought I tried that already and it resulted in an UnsuppertedoperationException due to not heaving a backing array-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ByteBuffer` doesn't have a backing array, it's a native `ByteBuffer` and you can use `bb.get(myByteArray);` (instead of `.array();`) to get the bytes from the buffer (assuming that `myByteArray` size is the amount of bytes in the buffer).